Serial console changes parameters when SUDOing
I'm working on a project where I need to connect a very old serial terminal to a linux device (a Raspberry).
The terminal uses 4800bps, 7 data bits and even parity. I have reconfigured the kernel command line to use these parameters and also the serial-getty service and I get a nice connection where I can login and use the system.
The problem comes whenever I use a command with sudo, all the data received by the terminal is garbage, it seems that the system is using different serial parameters when I use sudo, after the command ends the parameters seem to be restored again and continues working as expected...
How can I prevent these changes?

Does the root user have shell startup files that perform stty sane or other config commands?

@SottoVoce I have checked the profile and bashrc and there is no call to stty. I have added a stty at the top of /etc/profile and now at least I can have an interactive su terminal working but sudo still does the same. Also, I added some echo's to the profile and it seems that whatever does this is executed before the profile, and checking with strace bash I can't find any script executed prior to it... Any idea what could be executed before?

I suspect (but maybe I'm wrong) that use_pty may have something to do with the problem. See man 5 sudoers where it describes use_pty. Note regardless if it says the default is on or off (I believe the default changed from off to on around 1.9.14), your actual /etc/sudoers may specify Defaults use_pty xor Defaults !use_pty even out of the box.

@KamilMaciorowski BINGO! That was it! It was set as default in the sudoers file, commenting it made the thing work correctly ^_^
Please add your comment as response and I will accept it :)
Thanks a lot.

(1) I like my answers to be educative, not just "do this voodoo". I cannot fully explain why exactly use_pty results in what you have observed, so I won't add an answer. I won't mind if you post an answer. There is no need to mention my input, keep the answer technical. (2) Read this: How does the use_pty sudoers option prevent a persistence attack?.

@KamilMaciorowski I think I have found why it causes this problem. I have checked the source of "os_io.c" where it sets up the pipe between processes and when use_pty is enabled it creates a pseudo-terminal instead of piping the data directly, once created it calls to "setup_terminal_slave" and that call explicitly sets the data bits to 8 and that is what messes up the things. Also, this matches what I saw, not all chars were garbled, some were ok and I bet my ass that those were the ones that should had a parity bit of '0'.

So, thanks to @KamilMaciorowski I got it working.
Long story short: the problem is caused by use_pty in the sudoers file, commenting the Default use_pty line that my sudoers file had made it to work correctly.
Long story: well, after reading the source code of os_io.c I checked were it did the piping of data between processes and how it changed when use_pty is enabled. In the case of use_pty being enabled it creates a pseudo-terminal and pipes the data through it. The thing is that when the slave pseudo-terminal is created it has a function called setup_terminal_slave and this function explicitly sets the data bits to 8:
___HIDDEN int setup_terminal_slave
   ___P((int slave_fd),
        (slave_fd)
int slave_fd;)
{
  struct termios tios;
 
  if (tcgetattr (slave_fd, &tios) >= 0)
    {
      tios.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHOCTL | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
      tios.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | INLCR | ICRNL | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON | IXOFF);
      tios.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB | CLOCAL);
      tios.c_cflag |= (CS8 | HUPCL); // <---HERE, 8 data bits
#ifndef OCRNL
#define OCRNL 0
#endif
      tios.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST | ONLCR | OCRNL);
 
      if (tcsetattr (slave_fd, TCSANOW, &tios) >= 0)
        return 0;
    }
 
  return -1;
}

As my terminal uses 7 data bits and even parity the eight bit was being interpreted as the parity. breaking the text in the chars that should had a '1' as parity bit. And that exactly matches what I saw in the screen, not all the chars were broken, some were ok and others were just a blank square, so the chars that should had a '0' parity bit were shown ok and the ones that should had a '1' were shown as a "transmission error".
